# I want to switch python versions in paperspace

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

I want to switch my python version from 3.9.6 to 3.10 in paperspace. But it doesn't work.
So I need your help.

## device info

```
$root@nu1mmmnfz5:/notebooks/LoRA# cat /etc/*release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

```
$root@nu1mmmnfz5:/notebooks/LoRA# which python

/usr/local/bin/python
```

```
$root@nu1mmmnfz5:/notebooks/LoRA# ls /usr/local/bin/ | grep python

ipython
ipython3
python
python3
```

```
$ apt -y install python3.10
```

これが上手く入らないので苦戦しておりました。

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.16
```

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

```
 $ which python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.10
```

There are two, 'usr/local/bin' and 'usr/bin', and 'apt -y install python3.10' has gone into 'usr/bin'.

## Tried

```
$apt update -y
$apt upgrade -y
$apt -y install python3.10
```

update-alternatives
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, I created a custom image using the Paperspace default and override it using the code below and it worked.

```
FROM paperspace/gradient-base:pt112-tf29-jax0317-py39-20230125

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python && \
    apt update && \
    $APT_INSTALL python3.11 python3.11-dev  python3.11-venv  python3-distutils-extra && \
    ln -s /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/local/bin/python3 && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/local/bin/python && \
    curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.11 

ENV PATH=$PATH:/root/.local/bin

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN $PIP_INSTALL tensorflow jupyterlab

EXPOSE 8888 6006

CMD jupyter lab --allow-root --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser --ServerApp.trust_xheaders=True --ServerApp.disable_check_xsrf=False --ServerApp.allow_remote_access=True --ServerApp.allow_origin='*' --ServerApp.allow_credentials=True
```

Comment: This is the only approach that works for me. Maybe worth noting that you don't have to use `paperspace/gradient-base` as it is pretty heavy and not very actively maintained. Any docker image should work as long as it has jupyter lab running. I ended up using `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter` which at the moment comes with python 3.11.0rc1 out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can install pyenv and you will be able to switch versions at will.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: I did use pyenv . I could change python version . but python3- V can not changed .

Comment: python -V could changed python 3.9.16 to python3.10.10

Answer (score 0):

you can use `update-alternatives` to control python version
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux
maybe you should set  the priority 0  or the same number
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.11  0`

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --config  python
[sudo] password for wz: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.11   0         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7    0         manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/python3.11   0         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python2.7 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in manual mode
```

Comment: I did it . but i can not success . Please look at added imagefile

Comment: please look my latest update

Answer (score 0):

the best practice is not to change the system python version manually since many system services depend on it.

Also you should not install personal package using pip with root privilige for the same reason unless you know what it does.

you can use a version management to control the python env list like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) or [conda](https://www.anaconda.com)

Comment: I did use pyenv . I could change python version . but python3- V can not changed .

Comment: python -V could changed python 3.9.16 to python3.10.10

Answer (score 0):

Install miniconda and create environment with 3.10 in terminal mode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).